# Div elements sorted in searchable grid

Tags: jquery, datagrid

I want to do the following and don't know how to start since I am very new to web programming:

I have some objects stored in database, basically `css` boxes that a stored/showed between a div element. Those boxes are created from some data from a database. Now I want to show those boxes in a searchable and scrollable grid. Per row there have to be 4 boxes. Something like this when apple lists all products you can buy : [Apple](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/shop_ipad/ipad_accessories/cases)

Just fixed to a max size and with a insert scrollbar. I hope I could describe my problem in a understandable way and you guys can give me a hint how to manage this :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it with css. I created a mainGrid, where I can dynamiclly add new divs with help of jquery. To the added divs added I this in the css code: float: left. After that I did create a custom search function.